# Why is it true that if f(x, y, z) is a cyclic polynomial and f(y, y, z) = 0, (x-y) is a factor of f(x, y, z)?

Tags: polynomials

It is possible to understand the single variable factor theorem by observing that the long division of f(x) by (x-a) leaves an constant remainder, but that is not true for multivariate polynomials

Answer (score 2):

Of course. Consider $g(t,y,z)=f(y+t,y,z)$, it equals 0 for $t=0$, thus $g$ is divisible by $t$.